# Sabre Branded Fares - Brand Feature Type cost

Tags: xml, soap, sabre

when requesting branded fares from OTA_AirLowFareSearch

```html
<TPA_Extensions>
<BrandedFareIndicators SingleBrandedFare="true" MultipleBrandedFares="true" ReturnBrandAncillaries="true"/>
</TPA_Extensions>
```

The response we are getting is Brand features (BrandFeatureType) with applications Indicates if the service is free (F), not offered (N), chargeable (C), or displayed but not offered (D).
how can we identify the cost for chargeable brand feature types?

Answer (score 0):

maybe adding the Get Ancillary Offers in your request check the documentation for it.